# Extra watcher is always needed in directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My custom directive looks in general like this:

```
App.directive('myDir',function() {
    return {
        scope: {data:"="},
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.model={
                data:scope.data
            };
            scope.$watch('data', function () {
                scope.model.data = scope.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I have to define watch to copy changed (outside directive) `data` to object oriented `model`.
Is there other way? Should I always define extra watcher for that task?

Comment: You're not making it clear why you "need" to copy `.data` to `.model.data`. You could just use `.data`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do it when you pass an object to the directive with "data" attribute. Are you by any chance passing a primitive value to the directive (String, int, etc.) ?

In that case your scope in the directive ends up with a copy of the primitive value and the changes made outside the directive are not affecting the copy in the scope of directive.

To get around the problem, use a wrapper object like

```
$scope.data = {
   val: "foo"
};
```

and then pass that to the directive. As it passes an object *reference*, the changes made outside are reflected inside the directive as you are changing the same object.